# Recreating Odyssey Aatrox Sword (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I am very new to blender and now working on attempting to recreate the Odyssey Aatrox Sword. I am satisfied with the work I have done with the modeling, although it is far from perfect but, I have been struggling to recreate the material of the blade. Below are images of the sword reference images that I am working off. I am wondering how people much more experienced than me would try to recreate the gradients and smaller details.

In game model (The one that I am working off is in the top left)
[image]

Edit: Here is a blend file with my current work [image]

Comment: Consider sharing your blend, makes it way easier to create a shader using the real model: https://blend-exchange.com/ Btw: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.